# Coverting mysql query to firebase database

Tags: mysql, firebase

Can anybody know how to convert this mysql query to firebase database query(Android)

```
SELECT * FROM chat_info
WHERE receiver = '$sender' 
    and sender= '$receiver' 
UNION 
    SELECT * 
    FROM chat_info 
    WHERE sender='$sender' 
        and receiver='$receiver' 
ORDER BY sno 
DESC
```

Comment: Need to see your Firebase structure, as text please, no images or links. Also, please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

**Have never coded any Android-application, but here is documentation and an example:**

> [documentation.firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)
>
> [quickstart-for-android.github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)
>
> [read-&-write-data.firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
>
> [sort-data.firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data)
>
> [structure-your-database-correctly.firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6' // put this inside the 'build.gradle'-file

// Configure your database-rules =>

// Read from database and sort =>

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// My top posts by number of stars
String myUserId = getUid();
Query myTopPostsQuery = databaseReference.child("user-posts").child(myUserId)
        .orderByChild("starCount");
myTopPostsQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: implement the ChildEventListener methods as documented above
    // ...
});

// All examples are copied from firebase.google.com/docs
```